# Column detected as ValueLobDb instead of ValueNull in h2 v1.4.197

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, h2, liquibase

I am migrating a project from spring boot 1.5.19 to 2.4.5 (which is the current version of my issue).

During this migration process I came across a strange issue regarding an Enum with this stack trace :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown name value [] for enum class [***MyBusinessEnum***]
    at org.hibernate.type.EnumType$NamedEnumValueMapper.fromName(EnumType.java:433)
    at org.hibernate.type.EnumType$NamedEnumValueMapper.getValue(EnumType.java:417)
    at org.hibernate.type.EnumType.nullSafeGet(EnumType.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.type.CustomType.nullSafeGet(CustomType.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractType.hydrate(AbstractType.java:82)
```

This enum is expected to be null there and should not be mapped using fromName...

Many librairies were upgraded during this process, and I am looking for the culprit, if someone can give me some clues.
For example, liquibase as been upgraded from 3.5.5 to 3.10.3 (this is where my next investigation will be).
I am in a test context with an h2 database (still the same) and hibernate 5.2.4.Final (still the same).

---

While debugging, the only difference I saw is that on the old branch before the migration, I had my row like this :
[image: Working ResultSet]

Whereas, in my migration branch, my row look like this :
[image: Broken ResultSet]

And unfortunately, ValueLobDb.getString() return "" instead of null for this column...
For me, this explain why I get the exception on the enum, but I don't know why the resultSet is not exactly the same... and how I should fix this. I did not changed dataset nor inserted data for this test.

---

**Edit : It seems that the culprit is liquibase : by forcing the version to 3.5.5, it works again...
I wonder if it's a liquibase bug or not.**

**Edit : The issue appears between 3.5.5 and 3.6.2 (I can't test other versions...) ==> I am still interested for a tip as my goal is to upgrade versions... at least to the one used by spring boot. This would be sad to be stuck with liquibase 3.5.5 **

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I managed to make it work with liquibase 3.10.3 (and previous versions until 3.6.2 too...).

Those datas were loaded from a CSV file in a changeset using loadUpdateData.
I had to update my changetSet to specify the imported column type like this :

```
databaseChangeLog:
  - changeSet:
      id: name
      author: me
      changes:
        - loadUpdateData:
            tableName: table
            file: file.csv
            quotchar: '"'
            primaryKey: id
            columns:
              - column:
                  name: myColumnWhichIsAnEnumInJava
                  type: string
```

---

I don't really understand why in future liquibase version this is necessary and why this changes the behavior of how H2 is reading the data.

This is not mentioned here :
https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/load-update-data.html

But this seems a bit related to https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-3287